# Javascript XMLSerializer case sensitive

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-serialization, kml, google-earth

I'm generating a KML document in Javascript and i'm trying to use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer) to generate the XML file but it's generating all lower case tags even though i create the tags in capital in the DOM.

Is it the DOM that mangles the capitalization or the XMLSerializer? Is there any way to get around it or am I missing something? I've tried this in both Chrome and Firefox.

The KML document is to be imported into Google Earth and it seems it doesn't accept lower case tags.

Comment: Case-mangling makes it sound like you're treating the document as HTML not XML somehow. Do you have a code sample?

Comment: @MatthewWilson [Here's](https://gist.github.com/1032504) the part of the code that creates the KML structure and then serializes it. It's being executed from within a HTML5 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on testing in FF4, the following will work:

1. Use `document.createElementNS ("http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2", elementName)` instead of `document.createElement(elementName)`.
2. Use `elt.appendChild (document.createTextNode (text))` instead of `elt.innerHTML = text`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! A bit annoying that you have to do that with every element. Should be a createElement function on the document fragment object that uses the fragments namespace namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me (preserving case) in FF 5 beta in an XHTML page:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test() {
                var kml = document.getElementsByTagName("kml").item(0);
                window.alert (new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(kml));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="test()">
<kml id="kml" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>KML Samples</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <description>samples</description>
    <Style id="downArrowIcon">
      <IconStyle>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon28.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
    </Style>
  </Document>
</kml>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice job. was easier than I thought.

Comment: Not sure how much that helps since you already have a valid KML structure that you grab and then serialize. I'm building my KML document from the ground up with javascript.

Comment: OK, didn't know that when I posted.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you add elements with capital letters, the DOM manages them always in lower case. Just check it with firebug, you won't see uppercase tags.

In case your doctype is set to XHTML it even breaks standard compliance.

> in XHTML attributes and elements must be all lower-case

UPDATE: just checked following:

```
var test = document.createElement("DIV");
// test.outerHTML returns "<div></div>"
```

So already when you create the element, it's being parsed and converted to lowercase.

Comment: That's an HTML thing though. XML in general is case-sensitive and APIs should be case-preserving.

Comment: I somehow assumed that he is working in a html page, using it's DOM. Of course the XML will not work with Google as XML is case sensitive.

Comment: OK, so the KML is embedded in HTML. I think that should be OK as long as the page is XHTML and namespaces are suitably declared. "DIV" gets converted to "div" in your test because its an HTML element, I would hope the serializer would know to leave non-HTML elements alone.

Comment: I'm working in a HTML5 page but how much does that matter? As you can see in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1032504) i'm working on a separate document fragment.