# Case sensitive update of xml file using grunt-dom-munger?

Tags: xml, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to update one xml file like

```
<data Code="1"></data>
```

to

```
<data Code="2"></data>
```

I am getting result like

```
<data code="2"></data>
```

Here is my code for update

```
dom_munger:{
 dist:{
    options: {
          callback: function($){
            console.log($('data'));
            var code = parseInt($('data').attr('code'));
            console.log('Code to '+(code+1));
            $('data').attr('Code',code+1);

          }
        },
    src : 'data.xml'
 }
}
```

Please suggest the configuration to honour the case in xml file

Comment: i dont think this is possible. dom_munger uses [cheerio](https://npmjs.org/package/cheerio), and it doesnt seem that there is an option on reading/saving attributes camleCased...

Comment: Are there requirements that make grunt-dom-munger specifically needed, or could you use [grunt-xsltproc](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-xsltproc)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript XMLSerializer case sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386369/javascript-xmlserializer-case-sensitive)